# opengl: unable to draw left wall

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I am trying to start building a very basic room using opengl.  For some reason in the function drawWalls() the left wall doesn't get drawn or i'm misunderstanding the camera positioning.  Does anyone have any idea why I can't see the left wall when running this code?

my code:

```
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

/*defining colors used in the room*/
GLfloat black[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
GLfloat white[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
GLfloat brown[] = {165.0/255.0, 42.0/255.0, 42.0/255.0, 1.0};

void drawFloor()
{
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    glColor4fv(black);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -3.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, -3.0);
    glVertex3f(2.0, 0.0, -3.0);
    glEnd();
}

void drawWalls()
{
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    glColor4fv(white);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);


//draw left wall
glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 2.0);
glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 2.0);
glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

//draw front wall
            glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 3.0);
            glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 3.0);
            glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 3.0);
            glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 3.0);
            glVertex3f(2.0, 0.0, 3.0);
            glVertex3f(2.0, 1.0, 3.0);
    glEnd();
}
void display()
{
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  1.0, 0.0);
drawFloor();
    drawWalls();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat) w / (GLfloat) h, 1, 500);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
}

void idleFunc()
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("My room");
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(idleFunc);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't get culled because you are looking at it from the "back"?

Comment: Agree with @Spo1ler, culling would be my first guess too. Try calling `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);` and modifying your glPolygonMode call to `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);`

Comment: @Spo1ler: face culling is off initially, and never enabled in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you expect to see the left wall? It is off-screen (for any reasonable aspect ratios of your window). If we imagine some "world space", you'll have the folliwing situation: Your camera is placed at the origin and looking at almost diagonal vector. The lfet wall is placed at x=0 too, so you have almost 45 degrees between the view direction and the wall. Your frustum starts at distance 1 in front of the camera, and has a vertical FOV of 60 degrees, and the horizontal FOV is defined by the aspect ratio of the window. So if you make the window much wider than tall, you have a chance of seeing that wall.

Comment: Hi Derhass I think I am missing something in the gluLookat function.  I moved the x-position to 2 and can now see the wall but what still bothers me is when I increase the 4th parameter (which as far as I understand) should turn the camera to point down the positive x-axis it seems like i'm looking more down the negative x-axis the more I increase and decreasing the 4th parameter of gluLookat points the camera down the positive x-axis.

Comment: I don't know what exactly your problem is. Your confusion _might_ come from the fact the the matrices you are using establish a right-handed world space coordinate system. I get the impression that you might imagine as z pointing away, and x pointing right. But that's not the case, z is pointing towards you. However, as you look along +z, the positive x axis pints left.

Comment: Wow So even though the camera is pointing down positive z with the 6th parameter of gluLookat set to 1 positive x still is to the left?  It would make sense if the camera was pointing down negative z but...  Thanks for all your patient explanations btw much appreciated.

Comment: @user2094257: not "even when", but "because". You are looking from behind, so +x goes to the left.